# </script> in quotes ending script tag in html

Tags: jquery, html, css, quotes

I know very similar questions have been asked, and I've tried the answers. Here's my code:

```
    <script>
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet-mobile.css" />').appendTo('head');
        $('<script src="script-mobile.js"></scr' + 'ipt>').appendTo('head');
    }
    else {
        $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet-main.css" />').appendTo('head');
        $('<script src="script-main.js"></scr' + 'ipt>').appendTo('head');
    }
</script>
```

You can see the way I've got the closing  broken up to try and make it work, it looks like it will, but it doesn't. I've also tried "escaping" the slash, i.e: </script>, also doesn't work for me. Those are the answers I found on here... The CSS is running fine, so it's not the jquery itself, and if I take that script tag out and put it beneath the last closing tag, it works, so it's not something misnamed... Any ideas?

Comment: why you are using `+` sign here `$('<script src="script-main.js"></scr' + 'ipt>')`?

Comment: you need to add your code inside `document.ready` function. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r43vev8z/. You can use f12 to verify the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate the DOM of the page before it's loading. Use the ready handler `$(function() {…})`, [see the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet-mobile.css" />').appendTo('head');
        $('<script src="script-mobile.js"></script>').appendTo('head');
    }
    else {
        $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet-main.css" />').appendTo('head');
        $('<script src="script-main.js"></script>').appendTo('head');
    }
});
</script>
```

If it's to late, you have to use `document.write` in your page `<head>`:

```
<head>
    <script>
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet-mobile.css" />');
    document.write('<script src="script-mobile.js"></script>');
} else {
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet-main.css" />');
    document.write('<script src="script-main.js"></script>');
}
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Good sir, I thank you.
Oddly, adding document.write to the front of the css link screwed it up.. but it worked just fine on the script link, and the css link was already working so it wasn't necessary anyway. Something to do with DOM order, I'm sure. 

I'll try the first solution in the morning. :P Second solution worked beautifully, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
            $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet-mobile.css" />').appendTo('head');
            $('<script src="script-mobile.js"></scr' + 'ipt>').appendTo('head');
        }
        else {
            $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet-main.css" />').appendTo('head');
            $('<script src="script-main.js"></scr' + 'ipt>').appendTo('head');
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do

var value = '... -->';
  var valueNoComments = value.substring(4, value.length -3);
  document.write(value);